# s3cmd sync "remote copy" style operation in rsync or alternatives?

Tags: linux, synchronization, rsync

There is a very useful "remote copy" feature in s3cmd sync where any duplicate copies of a file existing in the source directory will not be transferred more than once to the S3 bucket, but a remote copy will take place instead, reducing the bandwidth taken for the transfer.

I have been searching for a similar solution to do a similar file transfer between 2 Linux servers. I've used rsync many times in the past, doesn't look like it has an option for this but perhaps I have missed something.

Simple example :

```
/sourcedir/dir1/filea
/sourcedir/dir1/fileb
/sourcedir/dir1/filec

/sourcedir/dir2/filea
/sourcedir/dir2/filed
/sourcedir/dir2/filee

/sourcedir/dir3/filea
/sourcedir/dir3/filef
/sourcedir/dir3/fileg
```

With a typical transfer, filea would be transferred across the network 3 times.

I'd like to transfer this file only once and have the remote server copy the file twice to restore it to the correct directories on the other side.

I need to perform a sync on a large directory with many duplicates in the fastest time possible.

I know it would be possible to script a solution to this, but if anyone knows an application with this native functionality then that would be great!

Thanks